# Pusher not working on my DCN Server, but works on my local machine. No error messages found

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, pusher, pusher-js

I developed a queueing system application using PHP Codeigniter and Pusher. On my local desktop, it works perfectly fine. I tried to deploy it on our DCN server, but pusher seems not working, user needs to refresh its browser just to display the data which is not supposed to be. It was supposed to display in real-time. I found no errors on my console, pusher just keep sending me these messages

```js
Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:ping","data":{}}]
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher:pong","data":{}}]
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:ping","data":{}}]
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher:pong","data":{}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Those messages indicate a successful connection to the Pusher service. If you are not receiving messages it would suggest you are either subscribed to the wrong channel or not subscribed to any channels. You mention this happened after deploying to a new environment - a common issue here is not updating the auth endpoint to ensure it is valid and reachable in the new environment. Have you made sure the authEndpoint is up to date and can be reached from the client? Its not uncommon to use `localhost` on local machines but this will not work for remote deployments.